# PostgreSQL Storing Foreign Key in Array in Column

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I am creating a a table that holds orders that we receive. ONe column will hold the product ID(s) and the quantity(s) as they could order 3 different items then next order 15 different items. So i have created it so the column order_products will be text[] that will hold arrays like so:

```
{{123234,3},{987765,3},{456678,65}}
```

The first part relating to another table with the product details then the quantity of that ordered.

My question is, is there a way to link the first part of each array (the part number) to the product table via PK or FK to create the relationship?

Answer (score 4):

Not formally.

Foreign keys to arrays were considered, but even then it was only planned for simple 1-dimensional arrays.

You can implement your own triggers to check and enforce the relationship.

Frankly, I strongly recommend normalizing your database unless you have an extremely good reason to use arrays for this purpose.

Comment: many thanks for the reply. How would you normalise a table when the number of products relating to an order can change dynamically?

Comment: Introduce a 1:n relationship via  a child table.

Comment: oh yeah of course! ive just seen how i should do it. 1 order can have many products. would it not be many to many though? as there could be 3 orders all with the same product being ordered?

Comment: Yes, that'd be m:n. Same deal, just need a join-table with the usual `primary key(order_id, product_id)`. Or if you're using some braindead ORM like Rails that can't cope with composite primary keys, `unique(order_id, product_id)` and a synthetic primary key.

Comment: ah yes thank you! i see how it works i completly forgot about the whole join table aspect! its PHP/postgreSQL im creating it in.
Many thanks